# C++: Need to toggle a switch to get dynamic resizeEvent() data in my Qt5 Window!? (Linux, X11)

Tags: c++, events, raspberry-pi, qt5, scaling

Iv'e been trying now for two days to just get a setup working for when I resize my QMainWindow in the QT5 program I'm working in.  I have been starting to add my own X11 code in but it's starting to feel ridiculous basically duplicating functionality that should be in there.

Then I just had a search in [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2mFuXsgJBoI) and there's someone showing that it indeed should work what I'm trying to do.

Basically I just want to get a stream of events that return the updated window size and position. Overriding the resizeEvent() and moveEvent() were the first things I tried but I only get an event triggered once I let go of the mouse. Not while I'm drag-scaling the window.
I have tried many things.

I'm starting to wonder if that's just not Working on Linux, or Raspbian Buster actually?
Or is there a setting that I need to toggle to get dynamic events? Is there some kind of 'performance mode' or something?    I'm using Qt5.12

```
void StreamWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)
{
    QSize size = event->size();
    printf("Size: %d, %d\n", size.width(), size.height());

    // HERE I'm planning to do stuff

    QMainWindow::resizeEvent(event);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: IMHO, it depends on the Window Manager (instead of your application) how many resize events are "fired" to the application when interactive resizing happens. I haven't worked in *ix/X11 for a longer time but even in Windows I remember that there was such an option at least in the past. (I didn't check whether it's still available.) In the past, it was necessary to make appearance somehow friendly for graphics H/W with low performance. Today, this is not such an issue anymore, at least, for average PCs with Windows. I can image that X11 window manager still provide this feature as well.

Comment: I dug quite a while to find such a config. feature in any X11 window manager, and finally found such in the [IceWM](https://ice-wm.org/manual/): _`OpaqueResize = 0` Window is immediately resized when dragged, no outline is shown._ You may have a look into the doc. of the window manager you're using to find a similar option.

Comment: Yes its starting to feel like that. Unless Iv'e completely missed some basics in Qt but I've done so much googling (ducking mostly actually) so I would have thought something would have come up.  I just checked and my desktop windows are all scaling 'opaquely ie not just with an transparent outlined shape. It might still be something like that though.

Comment: I see there's something that might be able to catch X11 events maybe I could try get that working and see if Qt is missing/ignoring some events.   QX11Info::peekEventQueue(QX11Info::PeekerCallback peeker, void *peekerData = nullptr, QX11Info::PeekOptions option = PeekDefault, qint32 peekerId = -1)